# adding datetime column to numeric dataframe forces values as numeric hence NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with numeric entries to which i wish to add some numeric codes as strings and these are taken as numbers too, although i try to specify dtype='str' and, since they do not look like numbers, they become NaNs:

```
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))
df['codes'] = pd.Series(['3/27', '3/22', '3/23', '3/27', '3/58', '3/29'], dtype='str')
df
```

which produces:

```
Out[1]: 
                   A         B         C         D codes
2013-01-01 -1.071662  0.322842 -1.364833  1.046144   NaN
2013-01-02 -1.779425  1.403387 -1.603079  2.117234   NaN
2013-01-03 -0.759267 -0.305942  1.310631  0.606185   NaN
2013-01-04  1.610275 -0.681264  0.800195  0.775496   NaN
2013-01-05  1.145720  0.252765 -1.512279 -0.222186   NaN
2013-01-06  1.267579 -1.412583 -0.270927  0.584454   NaN
```

What can i do to enter these codes as strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `index=df.index` for align new `Series` to `DataFrame`:

```
df['codes'] = pd.Series(['3/27', '3/22', '3/23', '3/27', '3/58', '3/29'], index=df.index)
```

Or assign list:

```
df['codes'] = ['3/27', '3/22', '3/23', '3/27', '3/58', '3/29']
```